# Sencha Touch store 'aftersync'-like event

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, extjs-mvc

I'm using a `ListView` with a store/ajax-proxy/json-reader/json-writer. I'd like to set the `ListView` to loading before I call `store.sync()`, and remove the loading once the response got back from the server.

Problem is, I don't know where I could hook in my call to be processed once the request is done, as all I'm doing is calling `sync()`.

`Store` has a `beforesync` event, what I'd like is something like `aftersync`. Any ideas how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By reading the Sencha Touch source code, it turns out that the `afterRequest` function is called just after the request is finished. This config option can be passed to any `Ext.data.Proxy` subclass. The two arguments passed are `request` and `success`.

Interesting though that it's not present in the [API docs](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/).