# in Sencha ExtJS or Touch, what is the best way to notify a store that the proxy has completed its call? the write event? refresh?

Tags: proxy, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

to me, it seems like there are events missing from the Store class.  namely, id like to be notified that the store has finished loading data remotely by its proxy after a sync.  the write event works... but is it the appropriate event to handle all CRUD operations?  im surprised there is no aftersync event.  note that there is a beforesync event.  any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. There's nothing as such "`aftersync()`" in Sencha Touch to notify us after store has finished loading data remotely by its proxy.

Similar links:-

- [Notify View about changes in Store from Proxy](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?153824-Notify-View-about-changes-in-Store-from-Proxy)
- [Sencha Touch store 'aftersync'-like event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672571/sencha-touch-store-aftersync-like-event)